# How to obtain key and secret for getting a refresh token for Dropbox API using rdrop2 and drop_auth()?

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, dropbox, rdrop2

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment directly asking the user Alejandro De Jesus who posted this answer ([Get a refresh token for Dropbox API using rdrop2 and drop_auth()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71393752/get-a-refresh-token-for-dropbox-api-using-rdrop2-and-drop-auth)) - where the key and secret come from?

Do I need to setup a dropbox app?

Why does this drop_auth_RT function work with the key+secret given, before I've put in my own keys? Wouldn't I be using someone else's account if I didn't change the credentials?

Comment: The `drop_auth_RT` posted in the answer there takes a `key` and `secret` argument that you can use to provide your own. Not sure if that person has accidentally posted theirs as default there..

Comment: Oh thanks @Axeman- this helped me figure it out. Those credentials are provided with the rdrop2 package as a default. The rdrop2::drop_auth function uses those too. They aren't the users personal credentials so I assume it is safe to leave those

Comment: Ah great thanks, I just edited them out of the answer but I'll rollback the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I just so happen to come across this post by accident, but I'm glad I found it.

I'm glad you found the solution to the issue, however if I'm not mistaken the key and secret have more to do with connecting to the Dropbox HTTP API and authorization tokens are the ones with account credentials.

Hope that bit of info helps.

Comment: Yes, the key and secret allow rdrop2 to use the Dropbox HTTP API; the OAuth token gives access to your files and account on dropbox. Thanks I do understand it much better now than when I posted.